# override python-social-auth built-in urls?

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I am using `python-social-auth` for Google authentication in my Django application. Can I override the `python-social-auth` URLs ? 
By default, it's `http://mydomain/login/google-oauth2/` and I need to change the URL as part of my view (get request) ; which has the end-point as `http://mydomain/login/`.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to override the URLs is to define your own ones pointing to the views and link it into your main urls.py file.

If what you are after for is to make `/login` automatically handle the Google auth backend, then you need to define a custom view for it that can call python-social-auth views to fire up the process.

Comment: If you're only looking to prefix `python-social-auth` URLs with something, you can add them to `urlpatterns` like so `path("oauth/", include("social_django.urls", namespace="social")),`.

I'm aware question isn't asking this directly, but maybe someone finds it useful.